# How to implement master lock that leads into locking one of multiple locks?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have the following classes:

```
class MyObjectManager {
    Map<String, MyObject> myObjects;

    void start(String myObjectName) {
        // Create or reuse myObject for given name and run its a() method.
    }

    void stop(String myObjectName) {
        // Create or reuse myObject for given name and run its b() method.
    }
}
```

```
class MyObject {
    void start() {
        // do something
    }

    void stop() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I need MyObject's start and stop methods to be ran synchronously for every MyObject instance and in the same order that MyObjectManager's methods were called with that myObjectName. However, I don't care about the order in which different MyObjects instances' methods are called. Initially, the map is empty and I create every MyObject the first time any of MyObjectManager's methods is called with specific myObjectName.

I think this can be solved by operating a master lock that synchronizes operations with myObjects map such as checking, adding and retrieving MyObjects instances. But after I obtained a MyObject instance either by retrieving it from the map or by creating it I need to lock on MyObject instance and release the master lock so that it's not kept unnecessarily locked while I execute MyObject.a() or MyObject.b().

I'm used to placing unlocking in `finally` blocks, so I imagine the code to be something like

```
void start(String myObjectName) {
    MyObject myObject = null;
    try {
        synchronized(myObjects) {
            myObject = createOrRetrieveMyObject(myObjectName);
            if (myObject == null) {
                // It's possible that myObjectName is invalid and MyObject will not be created.
                return;
            }
            myObject.lock();        ​
       ​ }
        myObject.start();
    } finally {
   ​     if (myObject != null) {
       ​     myObject.unlock();
        ​}
    }
}
```

That doesn't look pretty. Is there a better way?

Comment: myObject.lock() is it ReentrantLock?

Answer (score 0):

> I need MyObject's start and stop methods to be ran synchronously for every MyObject instance ...

I think that it might be more convenient do implement this synchronization logic inside `MyObject.start()` and `MyObject.stop()` (for instance you can make these methods `synchronized`), instead of requirement to use `lock()`+`unlock()` every time someone calls these methods.